# Pause the particular scene in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am developing a game using cocos2d-x. I want to pause the particular scene, when user press the pause button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pause a particular scene in two different ways

1.) Use `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();` to pause and `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();` to resume.

2.) Use `CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pause();` to pause and 
`CCDirector::sharedDirector()->resume();` to resume.

Comment: Backgrounmusic is not playing.When i press keyMenuClicked it is going to pause and i restart, background music is not playing. I am using the following code in appdelegate.cpp  CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic(); CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeeBackgroundMusic();

Comment: Here i too tried the same but its works fine for me ... In resume please add this piece of code     CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->setBackgroundMusicVolume(10);
and give a try

Comment: Where do i need to use, in applicationdidenterforeground.

Comment: Test the volume in which method you resume the background music